# Do i need to install gems required by a Sublime Text plugin into rvm's global gemset or will default do?

Tags: sublime-text-2, rvm, sublime-text-3, gem

If a Sublime Text 3 plugin asks me to install a gem for the plugin to work, do i need to tell rvm to install this gem into my global gemset for it to work properly or can I simply type 'gem install gem-name' regardless of what folder i've got open in my terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the path where the gem is going to be installed is accessible to the Sublime plugin, it shouldn't matter where you install it. If for some reason the plugin or build system can't find it, you'll either need to edit the settings to point to the correct directory, or make a symlink to a directory in Sublime's search path.

Comment: Cheers MattDMo.